# Tooltipster usage in the JSFiddle example

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, tooltipster

I have a working example of the tooltipster usage:
[working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/9qM6P/1/)

But my new own example does not work. 
[code, which does not work.](http://jsfiddle.net/gmox3df8/5/)
I am getting this:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/9qM6P/15/) must be not ID, but NAME:

```
code=[name="description"]
```